# Installing a pod fails, although it worked before setting up a new machine

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

After setting up a new machine, I am no longer able to install SwiftTask. I don't quite understand what's wrong. On the old machine, it worked without any problems or errors. This is the faulty pod:

`pod 'SwiftTask', :git => 'https://github.com/Cultivr/SwiftTask.git', :branch => 'swift/4.0'`

> [!] Error installing SwiftTask 
> [!] Failed to download 'SwiftTask'.

I ran `pod install --verbose` which displayed the following error: `fatal: reference is not a tree: bcf97f7012f3d0cf6d583456337ce7c45da18ce7`. Still doesn't make much sense to me since it is the same Podfile without any changes.

Answer (score 2):

You only have one branch 'master' on this repo:

```
pod 'SwiftTask', :git => 'https://github.com/Cultivr/SwiftTask.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Still don't get it. It worked before. As I said, the Podfile hasn't been changed and using master instead of the swift/4.0, still doesn't work and fails.

Comment: pod 'SwiftTask', :git => 'https://github.com/Cultivr/SwiftTask.git', :commit => 'ba8d9161176f23aa9d259495777a04092f48c860'

Try with the commit.

Comment: On your previous machine could it have been loading from a local cache?

Comment: @AshleyMills Probably but I don't remember most of that anymore. It's been some time since setting up that computer. Whatever, I ended up deleting SwiftTask from the Podfile and installed it manually. I feel rather stupid now.